# matrix operation in bash

Tags: bash, python, perl

the point is that I woul need to transpose a large file - 1600 times 80k but the entries are not tab delimited but just U and K so it looks like

```
UUUUTTTUTUTUUUTUTUT
TTUTUTUTUUTUTUTUTUT
```

is there a fdast way in bash, python or perl to do it?

Comment: transpose? a matrix?

Comment: yes...transpose a matrix with these to elements T and the other letter

Comment: What's the expected output for the given input?

Comment: the transposed matrix....i edited...

Comment: @choroba it is really just the transposition so rows to cols and the other way...

Comment: 80.000 x 1.600???

Comment: yes..is that a problem?

Comment: This is clearly a programming question, and should have been asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

1. perl

   ```
   perl -ne '
           chomp; 
           $l = length if $. == 1; 
           push @rows, [split //];
       } END {
           for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
               for ($j=0; $j<$.; $j++) {
                   print $rows[$j][$i];
               } 
               print "\n";
           }
   ' file
   ```
2. ruby has a handy `Array.transpose` method

   ```
   ruby -e 'puts IO.readlines(ARGV.shift)
                   .map {|line| line.chomp.split("")}
                   .transpose
                   .map {|row| row.join("")}
                   .join("\n")
   ' file
   ```

hmm, those will be VERY memory hungry. Another implementation

1. perl

   ```
   perl -ne '
           chomp; 
           if ($. == 1) {
               @data = split //;
           } else {
               @chars = split //; 
               $data[$_] .= $chars[$_] for 0..$#chars;
           }
       } END {
           print join("\n", @data), "\n";
   ' file
   ```
2. ruby

   ```
   ruby -e '
     file = File.open(ARGV.shift)
     data = file.gets.chomp.split("")
     file.each do |line| 
       line.chomp.split("").each_with_index do |char, idx| 
         data[idx] << char
       end
     end
     puts data.join("\n")
   ' file
   ```

---

I just can't let this go ;)

Benchmarking

```
               1 MB file         10 MB file           100 MB file
-----------------------------------------------------------------
         |   time  memory  |    time   memory  |     time  memory
perl v1  |  0.54s  85800k  |   4.59s  815140k  |        -       -
perl v2  |  0.47s   6776k  |   4.29s   22204k  |   41.88s 180404k
ruby v1  |  1.19s 137960k  |  14.63s  961736k  |        -       -
ruby v2  |  1.04s  12296k  |   9.75s   27816k  |  101.75s 185908k
gawk     |  1.15s 233056k  |  12.37s 2291404k  |        -       -
choroba  |  0.45s  76740k  |   3.90s  728888k  |        -       -
```

Choroba's perl wins the time race, but my 2nd implementations are way ahead memory-wise.

Transcript:

```
$ yes 123456789 | head -n 100000 > big
$ yes 123456789 | head -n 1000000 > bigger
$ yes 123456789 | head -n 10000000 > biggest
$ ls -l big*
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman   1000000 Jun 24 14:33 big
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman  10000000 Jun 24 14:33 bigger
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 100000000 Jun 24 14:33 biggest
$ time perl -n transpose_v1.pl big >/dev/null
0.54user 0.05system 0:00.98elapsed 61%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 85800maxresident)k
3080inputs+0outputs (15major+20501minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl -n transpose_v1.pl bigger >/dev/null
4.59user 0.39system 0:04.98elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 815140maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+202823minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl -n transpose_v2.pl big >/dev/null
0.47user 0.00system 0:00.48elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6776maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+819minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl -n transpose_v2.pl bigger >/dev/null
4.29user 0.01system 0:04.31elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 22204maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+5042minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl -n transpose_v2.pl biggest >/dev/null
41.88user 0.11system 0:42.01elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 180404maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+44590minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time ruby transpose_v1.rb  big >/dev/null
1.19user 0.10system 0:01.58elapsed 81%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 137960maxresident)k
5856inputs+0outputs (23major+33375minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time ruby transpose_v1.rb  bigger >/dev/null
14.63user 0.48system 0:15.12elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 961736maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+239378minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time ruby transpose_v2.rb  big >/dev/null
1.04user 0.02system 0:01.07elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 12296maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+2020minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time ruby transpose_v2.rb  bigger >/dev/null
9.75user 0.02system 0:09.79elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 27816maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+6051minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time ruby transpose_v2.rb  biggest >/dev/null
101.75user 0.21system 1:41.99elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 185908maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+45600minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time gawk -f transpose.gawk big >/dev/null
1.15user 0.12system 0:01.28elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 233056maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+58542minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time gawk -f transpose.gawk bigger >/dev/null
12.37user 1.03system 0:13.40elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2291404maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+580302minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl transpose_choroba.pl  big >/dev/null
0.45user 0.04system 0:00.58elapsed 84%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 76740maxresident)k
112inputs+0outputs (1major+18282minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time perl transpose_choroba.pl  bigger >/dev/null
3.90user 0.37system 0:04.28elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 728888maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+181291minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: Ruby? I have to remember that. +1

Comment: It's a nice language. A lot slower than perl for a job like this.

Answer (score 2):

The following will transpose a matrix with an arbitrary number of rows and columns using near-zero memory resources.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 $(head -n1 "$1" | wc -c)); do 
    awk -v c=$i 'BEGIN{FS=""}{printf $c}' "$1"
    echo
done
```

Save it with a meaningful name (e.g. `transpose.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x transpose.sh`) and use it like this:

```
./transpose.sh matrix.txt
```

Output:

```
UT
UT
UU
UT
TU
TT
TU
UT
TU
UU
TT
UU
UT
UU
TT
UU
TT
UU
TT
```

How it works:

- `$(head -n1 "$1" | wc -c)` : count the number of columns
- `for i in $(seq 1 $num_cols); do ... done` : Run this loop for each column
- `awk -v c=$i 'BEGIN{FS=""}{printf $c}' "$1"` : Parse the matrix file. The current column number (from the current iteration of the parent loop) is saved in `awk` variable `c`. Use it in order to print just all the values of this column (`$c`) sequentially (without new lines - using `printf`)

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr;
while (my $line = <>) {              # Read the input line by line.
    chomp $line;                     # Remove a newline.

    # Distribute the characters to subarrays of the array:
    push @{ $arr[$_] }, substr $line, $_, 1
        for 0 .. length($line) - 1;
}
print @$_, "\n" for @arr;
```

You'll need lots of memory to transpose large matrices, though.

Comment: do you think it would work with 80k times 1600?

Comment: It depends. How much memory do you have? Is the machine 64bit?

Comment: I was able to process a 123 MB file with less than 10 GB memory in 1m10s.

Comment: Nice perl script ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

Create a awk script `transpose`

```
BEGIN { FS = "" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str""a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}
```

and start with

```
gawk -f transpose <your_input_file> > <your_output_file>
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo
UUUUTTTUTUTUUUTUTUT
TTUTUTUTUUTUTUTUTUT

% gawk -f transpose foo
UT
UT
UU
UT
TU
TT
TU
UT
TU
UU
TT
UU
UT
UU
TT
UU
TT
UU
TT
```